# ¿Cómo convertir un archivo binario a ASCII en UNIX?

Tags: archivo, unix, grep, ascii

Estoy buscando una cadena determinada en un archivo bastante grande:

```
$ ls -lh archivo.csv
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yo yo 723M Dec 10 10:46 archivo.csv
```

Si utilizo `grep` me encuentro con que el resultado no aparece, sino solo la indicación de que hay alguna en el archivo:

```
$ grep "12345" archivo.csv
Binary file archivo.csv matches
```

Así que mirando el tipo de archivo de que se trata observo que es...

```
$ file archivo.csv
archivo.csv: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Lo he convertido a UNIX con el comando `dos2unix`:

```
$ dos2unix archivo.csv
dos2unix: converting file archivo.csv to Unix format...
```

Pero el problema sigue apareciendo:

```
$ grep "12345" archivo.csv
Binary file archivo.csv matches
```

Me he dado cuenta después de que `grep` tiene una opción de buscar en archivos binarios, la `-a`:

```
$ grep -a "12345" archivo.csv
12345  esto es un test
```

Pues `man grep` indica que:

```
-a, --text
    Process a binary file as if it were text; 
    this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
```

Pero así y todo me pregunto, ¿cómo puedo convertir este archivo binario a ASCII?

Comment: No es posible simplemente convertir "binary" a "ASCII", porque ningua es un formato, y como convertir desde uno a otro depende completamente en que contiene el archivo. Y saber que es un .CSV no ayuda mucho--un archivo de CSV puede tener cualquier formato, en cualquier idioma y en cualquier formato. Por eso, estoy votando a cerrar esta pregunta como "demasiada amplia."

Comment: También, como formado, no es una pregunta de programación, sino de usar Unix.

Comment: @Flimzy claro, el formato es irrelevante en UNIX y no lo uso para nada en la pregunta, solamente como identificador del archivo. Nótese que SOes actualmente no es solo SO sino [algo así como SO + SE + SF](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/211/83). De [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), esto encaja en _herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores_. En cuanto a la pregunta en sí, cierto, el título contiene incorrecciones conceptuales dadas por cómo lo interpreta `grep`. No sé qué título encajaría mejor, ¿qué recomiendas?

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta es más ¿Cómo convertir un archivo de texto desde el  formato para Windows a Unix? o algo así?

Comment: No, pues para tal cosa `dos2unix` sería la respuesta pero lo probé y no funcionó. Es algo así como "¿Cómo puedo convertir un archivo para que `grep` ya no lo interprete como binario?".

Comment: Entonces obtengo que es demasiada amplia.. porque como hacerlo depende en el caso. Si tu archivo es un "tar", por ejemplo, la respuesta es "No lo hagas" o talvez "Puedes usar base64".

Comment: Sí tu pregunta solamente es "¿Cómo grep determine que un archivo es binary?", puedes preguntarlo... pero eso es diferente que convirtir el archivo (que a muchas veces no es posible).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Realmente, todos los archivos son binarios (obviamente), pero cuando a dicha codificación binaria le damos una interpretación X, entonces decimos que tiene la codificación X (o están codificados en X).

En tu caso, el archivo **no es binario**, tiene la codificación **ISO-8859** y por tanto debes usar herramientas que sepan trabajar (entiendan) dicha codificación.

El parámetro `-a` de `grep` fuerza a que ignore ciertos códigos que no son interpretados como una cadena de texto ASCII (ej. el `\x0`).

Así, en tu caso, deberías convertir dicho archivo a otro más adecuado a tus herramientas, para lo cual, lógicamente existen muchas herramientas pero a mí, la que más me gusta es [iconv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Core_utilities&redirect=no#iconv) que en tu caso sería algo como (de la misma ref)

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 foo >foo.utf
```

(NOTA: en lugar de a utf podrías pasarlo a ASCII como pides, pero entonces quizás se pierda información existente en el archivo original como por ejemplo el símbolo `§`).

Por ejemplo, tomando [este](http://vancouver-webpages.com/multilingual/samples7.var) archivo tenemos

```
$ file samples7.var
samples7.var: HTML document, ISO-8859 text
$ grep Deut samples7.var
Binary file samples7.var matches
$ grep -a Deut samples7.var
<TITLE>German / Deutsch S▒d (ISO Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1)</TITLE>
<H1>German / Deutsch S▒d (ISO Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1)</H1>
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 samples7.var > samples7.var.utf
$ file samples7.var.utf
samples7.var.utf: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text
$ grep Deut samples7.var.utf
<TITLE>German / Deutsch Süd (ISO Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1)</TITLE>
<H1>German / Deutsch Süd (ISO Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1)</H1>
```

Que, como vemos, permite visualizar y filtrar correctamente sin perder información.

Ya por último, usar `dos2unix` no te sirve en este caso, porque el comando exige que los archivos sean de texto plano, y tu archivo no tiene esa codificación (véase [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html)).

Comment: Qué explicación tan fantástica, ¡muchas gracias! Sólo me queda la duda: ¿por qué se pierde el símbolo `§`?

Comment: Porque ese símbolo no existe en la codificación ASCII. Un punto de partida para aprender sobre ello podría ser https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_de_archivo

Comment: @fedorqui: Note que todavía el archivo no es ASCII...

Comment: Se podría hacer también en un solo paso utilizando un pipe `iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 samples7.var | grep Deut`

Answer (score 5):

Es algo amplio lo que preguntas, ya que para mí dependería de qué es lo que contiene el archivo y qué es lo que quiero extraer de él. Si te sirve la manera en que `grep` está convirtiendo el archivo binario a texto y no te interesa más información del archivo que la que te brinda, puedes simplemente usar:

```
grep -a '*' archivo.csv > archivo_texto.csv
```

Comment: ¡Interesante método! Nótese que hace falta poner `*` entre comillas para que no expanda a todos los elementos en el diretorio en el que se trabaja. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Gracias a ti por la corrección :)